# How to convert between different units of resistivity

Tags: resistivity

Some data sheets specify units of resistivity as Ω/sq/mil. How could I convert that to units of Ω-cm?

Comment: `Some data sheets...` what datasheets? Give links or names, please.

Comment: I did not know what is policy of promoting company products, but a lot of silver conductive ink companies specify their ink resistivity with the above units in their data sheet

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct conversion. They are different concepts:

- Ω - total resistance, as scalar quantity
- Ω-<length> - bulk resistivity of a 3-D material
- Ω/square - sheet resistivity of a 2-D material
- Ω/<length> - linear resistivity of a 1-D wire
- Ω-<area> - contact resistance

For example, you can convert between bulk resistivity and sheet resistivity if you know the thickness of the sheet.

Comment: How does contact resistance work out as Ω/[L]²?

Comment: @Hearth: It's resistance through a sheet (normal to the plane of the sheet) rather than along the surface.

Comment: Wouldn't that have units of Ω·[L]², not Ω/[L]²?

Comment: @Hearth: OK, yes. That would be the correct units, given that you divide by area to get the total resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that Dave Tweed said is correct, but I still think that there is more to your question.

We need to see some example datasheets to fully understand the issue. I found these, two different datasheets for silver ink. Let's assume that their characteristics are similar.

The first has units of \$ \Omega /square/mil \$. *Square* has no units, so this can be simplified to \$ \Omega /mil \$. You would divide by the thickness to get resistance, so they are sloppy with their units, it should be \$ \Omega \text{-}mil \$

The second has units of \$ \Omega \text{-}cm \$. These are normal units for volume resistivity.

So, to convert the first to the second, divide by the number of mils in a cm (393.7).

\$ 0.005 \Omega\text{-}mil \frac{cm}{393.7 mil} = 12.7 \mu \Omega\text{-}cm\$

This is close, remember that these are not identical inks, just similar.

[image]

https://kayakuam.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ag500a-silver-conductive-ink.pdf

[image]

https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/791881

A good discussion about volume resistivity:
[What's a conceptual way to understand ohm-cm?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/500995/whats-a-conceptual-way-to-understand-ohm-cm)